# owl type inference in sparql

Tags: types, owl, inference

Given class A, property P in domain A, and class B, that is defined as equivalent to A when property P has value "B"

```
@prefix : <http://sample.org/ont#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://sample.org/ont#> .

<http://sample.org/ont#> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

:P rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
   rdfs:domain :A .

:A rdf:type owl:Class .

:B rdf:type owl:Class ;
   owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                         owl:intersectionOf ( :A
                                              [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                owl:onProperty :P ;
                                                owl:hasValue "B"
                                              ]
                                            )
                       ] .

:b rdf:type :A , owl:NamedIndividual ;
   :P "B" .
```

Protége displays the type :B as expected inferred type of individual :b according to definition of the class :B.

The SPARQL query

SELECT * WHERE { 
    :b a ?type
}

in the SPARQL Query view of Protége returns however only the class :A.

Why doesn't it also return the inferred class :B?

Thanks.

PS: The model is backed by the Pellet reasoner

PPS: The mentioned SPARQL query using Jena's reasoner OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF in a Java application returns the expected class :B as a type of the individual :b. The discussed problem seems to be an issue of the SPARQL query view of Protége.

Comment: You should include details of precisely what SPARQL query you executed and against what endpoint it was executed against.

Comment: I've added the information to the main post